# How to Input Multiple Columns Under One Primary Key?

Tags: sql, asp.net

Using **Microsoft Visual Web Developer** and  **MSSQL** as the database,
is there a way to insert multiple values under one primary key? Just like the common systems used in grocery stores(eg. 7-11)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if i understand your question, you are trying to store same value that you call primary key i.e. unique column without null, then you cannot! Primary key has to be unique and it will not accept null either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can never do that for Primary Keys are unique with each other what you can do is to insert multiple values under one type/brand/dealer.

For Example:

```
INSERT INTO Product(PKID,Name,Quantity,Dealer) VALUES (NEWID(),'Product1','100','CompanyX')
INSERT INTO Product(PKID,Name,Quantity,Dealer) VALUES (NEWID(),'Product2','121','CompanyX')
INSERT INTO Product(PKID,Name,Quantity,Dealer) VALUES (NEWID(),'Product3','200','CompanyY')
INSERT INTO Product(PKID,Name,Quantity,Dealer) VALUES (NEWID(),'Product4','50','CompanyY')
INSERT INTO Product(PKID,Name,Quantity,Dealer) VALUES (NEWID(),'Product5','53','CompanyY')
```

Result:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|                PKID                |  Name  |Quantity|  Dealer|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
|E04B64F7-8B84-465A-91F3-635DBDA242B0|Product1|     100|CompanyX|
|49BB0054-A654-4877-B991-8300F660B72A|Product2|     121|CompanyX|
|1DBE1BBF-89AF-482B-9BB7-DC2B1AA2932E|Product3|     200|CompanyY|
|6EC8A994-7D40-40C0-B390-2761857EF42B|Product4|      50|CompanyY|
|5DFFB38E-C564-4DDF-946A-08C47DFC044F|Product5|      53|CompanyY|
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

In this case, you added multiple values under one ***dealer***.

Comment: rigel1121 , any alternatives , that i can put multiple name under one PKID?

Comment: I think there is no alternative for that. Sorry. What you can do is my example above.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do another thing
Make master table for primary key or id

ex. master table 1 for fruit
and 2 for veg.

make another table into insert all data...
like apple,orange comes under 1
veg. comes under 2...

so you can manage all data very well. . .